# Facebook friendslist always null

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook4j i tried to get the friendslist  but i am getting always null value only

```
ResponseList<Friendlist> friendList = facebook.getFriendlists();
for(Friendlist facebookFriends : friendList) {
             generateJSON(facebookFriends);
   }
```

Why it always returns null. Could anyone provide example

Comment: how would i get friends list

Answer (score 0):

```
if($fb_user_id)
{  
    try 
    {       
        $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
        sort($friends['data']);
        $userfriends=$friends;
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
    {
        echo ($e->getMessage());
    }
}
else
{
   echo 'error';
}
```

I am getting friends list using this code. Try it out.